# Making series cointegrated if they are not cointegrated?

Tags: cointegration

I am fairly new to pairs trading. I was looking at a couple of series and testing whether they were cointegrated to see if I could apply a pairs trading strategy to them.

I tested the series for cointegration using the Engle-Granger Two Step Method using the R package `egcm` and I also used an augmented Dickey-Fuller test found [here](http://www.vikparuchuri.com/blog/time-series-cointegration-in-r/). Both tests indicated that my series were not cointegrated.

Now my question is - is there any way to make them cointegrated? can transformations or any other method be applied to achieve this purpose?

As a side note, using the augmented Dickey-Fuller test resulted in a p-value of 0.0578 which is fairly close to the cut.

Comment: There is no reason to believe 0.05 is magical.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So you think the series might still be appropriate for pairs trading?

Comment: I have no idea, really. I have little expertise in time series analysis, & I generally believe in investing in passive index funds.

Comment: Oh I see - in any case I continue to be most interested in learning whether there are ways of making two series cointegrated if they are not so already

Comment: That does seem like a reasonable question.